# First order differential equation confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $$y' + e^{y'}-x=0$$ that I have simplified like so $$e^{y'}=x-y'$$ $$\ln e^{y'}=\ln (x-y')$$ $$y'= \ln (x-y')$$ but I do not know how to solve this further to obtain the general solution. I have done first order linear differential equation strategies so far. How should I get about doing this question with the strategies I have?

Comment: Is this really a first order differential equation? I doubt.

Comment: Haha yes I know that. I meant that I only know how to solve first order differential equations so I do not know how to proceed with the tools I have.

Comment: The solutions to this can't expressed with elementary functions.

Comment: Can you show how your simplification works? It looks like you're thinking that $\log(x+y)=\log x \log y$, which is not right.

Comment: Your solution works (regarding your mistake) if you had $y' + e^{y}-x=0$ as given equation. Check your source again.

Comment: @AmirHossein, it is $e^{y'}$. It's from a past exam paper.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, is it fine now? Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (revised) simplification doesn't really simplify because it separates the $y'$s from each other. The productive thing to do would be to rewrite it to
$$ x = y'+e^{y'} $$
and work from there.

First, let $g(u) = u+e^u$; then the equation becomes $x = g(y')$ or $y'=g^{-1}(x)$. In this form we get the solution
$$ y = \int_1^x g^{-1}(t)\, dt + C$$
This integral is not nice, but (noting that $g^{-1}(1)=0$, which is why I chose $1$ as the lower limit) we can flip it around to
$$ y = xg^{-1}(x) - \int_0^{g^{-1}(x)} g(u) \,du + C $$
and $g$ is easy enough to integrate so we get
$$ y = xg^{-1}(x) - \frac{g^{-1}(x)^2}2 - e^{g^{-1}(x)} + C_1 $$
(with $C_1=C+1$). With a bit of help from Wolfram Alpha we find $g^{-1}(x) = x - W(e^x)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). We can plug this in to get
$$ y = \frac{x^2}2 - \frac{W(e^x)^2}2 + e^{x-W(e^x)} + C_2$$
By the definition of $W$ we have $e^{-W(e^x)} = W(e^x)/e^x$, so this further simplifies to
$$ y = \frac{{x^2} - (W(e^x)-1)^2}{2} + C_3 $$
If still not exactly pretty, this is at least a "closed form" modulo the $W$ function.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now :) I think I just went straight to getting rid of that $e$. But is there any way to do this without getting $W$ into the picture? Since it is from a past year paper, I am sure the instructor meant for it to be done without using Wolfram Alpha haha :)

Comment: @Artemisia: No -- given my last simplification, if $y$ had an elementary closed form we would have $W(t) = 1+\sqrt{\log^2 t - 2y(\log t)+2C_3}$, but $W$ is known not to be elementary.

Answer (score 1):

I also suppose a typo somewhere. Using a CAS, I did not get any solution beside $$y=c+\int_1^x \left(t-W\left(e^{t}\right)\right) \, dt$$ which is not very pleasant.

Even $y' + e^{y}-x=0$ is not very pleasant, the solution being $$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-2 \log \left(c+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Yeah. I think the question setter wishes for this to be solved via some sort of variable substitution. Thank you :)